# WPF binding to property in class

Tags: wpf, windows-phone-7, xaml

I am attempting to bind a textbox to a property.

The property I would like to bind to the textbox is in a separate class:

```
public void errorText {get;set;}
```

In my mainpage I have set the data context to an instance of the class that the errorText property resides in so that now my mainpage is aware of my class with the property:

```
this.Datacontext = instance;
```

now in my xaml I am binding the property to the textbox:

```
 <TextBlock Height="121" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="100,613,0,0" Name="TextBlockForErrorsMainPage" Text="{Binding errorText}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="285" Foreground="#FFEF1212" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
```

I am having no joy when I run the application though...any help with this?

Thanks.

Comment: When do you set errorText? If it's after binding has first occurred, the binding won't update because there's no notification on your property. This is binding 101.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning void

```
public string errorText {get;set;}
```

And may need to also implment iNotifyPropertyChanged.

If you set the value before Initialize() then the UI will see that value.